# Upload Images In SugarCRM Community Edition

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I already have a list of Contacts and now I would like to upload images for all the Contacts in a SugarCRM instance. However this feature is not available in SugarCRM CE. Can anyone provide assistance?

Answer (score 0):

Out-of-the-box you can't add images for Contacts module in SuiteCRM or SugarCRM CE. You would need to implement a custom solution.